# how to break heading into parts and add html span tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am not very good with jQuery but I have a question to ask.

I have a heading

```
<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
    This is: a heading (in different parts)
</h1>
```

The question is, is that possible that with the help of jquery, I can convert the above heading tag into

```
<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
    This is: <span class="block1">a heading (<span class="block2">in different parts</span>)</span>
</h1>
```

kindly guys help me how can i do that with jquery.

Comment: think of how you could explain where each block starts and ends. If you can define that properly, it can be coded. Currently... not so much.

Comment: How your HTML markup is generated? You should look at this instead

Comment: On what event would you like this to happen?

Comment: well i m using genesis framework and its generating that heading code, but on some specific page i want to alter the heading and add span tag in it.

Comment: What A. Wolff said. Otherwise, it can be done with a regular expression, but that would only work well if the format of the heading is always the same (colon and parenthesis in the same place).

Comment: Yes no problem, @Ted ... if is that possible, then please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible regex:

```
var textStr = $('.entry-title').text(), //This is: a heading (in different parts)
    bit = textStr.match(/(.*:)(.*\()([\d\w\s]*)/), //I simplified this, overwrote it the first time
    newHtml = bit[1] +'<span class="block1">'+bit[2]+'<span class="block2">'+bit[3]+'</span>)</span>';

$('.entry-title').html(newHtml );
```

Okay, to explain what's happeining here, first the simple lines:

```
var textStr = $('.entry-title').text()  
//just fetching the text within that element

newHtml = bit[1] +'<span class="block1">'...
//creating an html string from the bits from the regex match

$('.entry-title').html(newHtml );
//setting the elements html contents to the new string.
```

Now for the regex. The match method returns an array of elements corresponding to whatever is in '()'. More info can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp). So here it is broken down:

```
(.*:)
```

the **.** is a wild card for any character except for a new line, the ***** tells it to continue until it finds the next piece of the regex, which is the **:**

```
(.*\()
```

same as the previous, except we want it to stop on the **(**. Since that's a special character, we escape it with a \

```
([\d\w\s]*)
```

Last we want any digit **\d**, word **\w**, or space character **\s**, so that it will stop when it hits the last ')'.

Per change in req, use this instead:

```
bit = textStr.match(/(.*:)([\d\w\s]*)\(([\d\w\s]*)/),
newHtml =   bit[1] +'<span class="block1">'+bit[2]+'<span class="block2">('+bit[3]+')</span></span>';
```

Comment: Can you please describe little bit how you did this?

Comment: please 1 more thing i have to ask, what if i want to add span tag before first **(** round bracket.

Comment: Thank you again @Ted, but again i have a question is that possible i can add <span> before first ( ... round bracket in the heading

Comment: Sure, where would the closing tag be?

Comment: `<h1 class="entry-title">This is: <span class="block1">a heading <span class="block2">(in different parts)</span></span></h1>` Is that possible? sorry i say my mistake later.

Comment: Sure, change these two lines:bit = textStr.match(/(.*:)([\d\w\s]*)\(([\d\w\s]*)/),
     newHtml =  bit[1] +'<span class="block1">'+bit[2]+'<span class="block2">('+bit[3]+')</span></span>';

Comment: sorry--something got lost in the copy paste. I edited the end of my post with the change

Comment: You are just Awesome... thank you @Ted .. now i m thinking to learn about jQuery.. its very important. Thank you again Ted.