# jQuery insert SPAN in H1 before special character

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to change

```
<h1>Headline Text - More Headline Text</h1>
```

to

```
<h1><span class="something">Headline Text</span> - More Headline Text</h1>
```

with jQuery.

First, I have to check, if there is a "-" in the h1-tag on the whole website. If there is, I'd like to insert the span-tag with a customized class BEFORE the "-". Otherwise just leave the h1-tag untouched.

Is this possible?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27425822/4385913) helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('h1').each(function(){
  if($(this).html().indexOf("-") !== -1)
  {
     var html = $(this).html();
     var newhtml = html.split("-")[0];
     newhtml = "<span class='something'>"+ newhtml +"</span>"
     $(this).html(newhtml + "- " + html.split("-")[1])
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31rttyz9/1/)

Comment: Works great, thanks alot! Even works with nested tags, eg `<h1><a href="...">Text - More Text</a></h1>`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var controls =$('h1').html();
  var g=controls.split("-");
  if(g.length>1)
  {
    var texts='<span>'+g[0]+'</span> - '+g[1];
    alert(texts);
    $('h1').html(texts);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Headline Text - More Headline Text</h1>
```

Comment: If I only could choose all answers, yours perfectly fits as well. But I added an addidional else function to @Kartikeya, just worked out better for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('h1').each(function() {
  var found = $(this).text().indexOf('-') !== -1;
  if (found) {
    var arr = $(this).text().split('-');
    $(this).html('<span class="something">' + arr[0] + '</span> - ' + arr[1]);
  }
});
```

```css
.something {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Headline Text - More Headline Text</h1>
<h1>Headline Text - More Headline Text</h1>
<h1>Headline Text</h1>
<h1>Headline Text - More Headline Text</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, very good solution, but i chose @Kartikeya solution because of the use of nested HTML-Tags within the h1-tag. But is a perfect answer to my querstion, I didn't mention the nested-tags. You guys are just great! Many thanks!